# Left join no funciona aunque todo parece coincidir (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, join

Holi, estoy intentando unir dos dataframes en los que la primera columna coincide pero, aunque no recibo ningún error, no se unen bien. Parto de un df con 1 variable y 273 observaciones y otro con 6 variables y 274, pero obtengo uno con 6 variables y 728 observaciones.
Verifiqué los nombres de las columnas, removí espacios, probé usando la funcion merge en lugar de join, pero el resultado es el mismo. Alguna idea de que puede estar sucediendo?

El código es:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
library("writexl")

#Obtengo el dataframe con la informacion de ayer 
url_base = "https://api.cafci.org.ar/estadisticas/descargar/informacion/diaria/2/"
url_fecha = format(Sys.Date()-1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
url = paste0(url_base, url_fecha)
df = read.xlsx(url)

df[df == "Benchmark: S&amp;P Merval"] = "Benchmark: S&P Merval"

df$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión = as.character(df$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión)
df$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión = gsub('\\s+', '', df$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión)
df$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión = replace(df$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión, grepl("^\\s*$", df$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión) == TRUE, NA)

#Obtengo el df base
df_base = read.xlsx("C:\\...\\base_FCI.xlsx")
df_base$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión = as.character(df_base$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión)
df_base$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión = gsub('\\s+', '', df_base$Fondo.Común.de.Inversión)

#Los uno
df_FINAL= df_base %>% right_join(df,by="Fondo.Común.de.Inversión")
```

El output de df es (la barra / marca las columnas):

> FCI / Patrimonio.Neto

> 1 / NA

> 2 / Region:Argentina / 42552496439.54

> 3 / Duration:Mayora1yMenorIgual3Años / 416569063.01

> 4 / Benchmark:S&PMerval / 416569063.01

Y el de df_base es solamente la columna FCI pegada y copiada en un excel tal cual.

Cuando uso el join me devuelve:

> 1 / Region:Argentina / 42552496439.54

> 2 / Duration:Mayora1yMenorIgual3Años / 416569063.01

> 3 / Benchmark:S&PMerval / 416569063.01

> 4 / Benchmark:S&PMerval / 11255236201.99

> 5 / Benchmark:S&PMerval/ 3390207.63

No todos los datos de FCI tienen un numero asociado, en esos casos aparece el espacio en blanco.

La idea sería que en el df_base aparezcan los datos de Patrimonio Neto también.

Comment: ¿Podrías subir a alguna ubicación en línea al archivo `base_FCI.xlsx` o al menos poner un ejemplo de lo que contiene? De esa forma se podría reproducir el error y quizás encontrar una solución. También ayudaría mucho que menciones cuál es el resultado esperado. ¿Cómo esperas que se vean tus datos una vez que el join funcione como quieres? ¿Cuántas filas y cuantas columnas? ¿Cuáles?

Comment: Listo! Gracias por contestar :)

Comment: Creo que el problema es que en la columna FCI tienes valores repetidos, por ejemplo, `Moneda:PesoArgentina` está 18 veces, entonces tienes 18 valores distintos de combinaciones de `Patrimonio.Neto`*`Moneda:PesoArgentina` y 18*18=324 veces que aparece la fila en el join y así hasta 728.Para hacer este join necesitas identificadores únicos de fila porque hay mediciones repetidas. ¿Son de distintas fechas y eso está implícito en el Excel?